# Sidebar está sob a imagem, como tirar

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo um site no wordpress, em uma página coloquei um sidebar,
porém o mesmo está ficando sob a imagem do topo da página.
Segue o link para visualização http://caioborges.com/site/loja/.

Answer (score 0):

Você diz o menu fixo que acompanha ao rolar a página? Se for, isso adicione a seguinte classe CSS:

```
header .polar-sticky-menu.sticky {
position: absolute; !important}
```